# Python list format string with list item inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```
my_list = ['Ciao', True, 2.5, 18, 0x001, 8+15j, [5,'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]]]
```

I would like to print the formatted output, however, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Lesson02\lesson02_ex01.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(f'{i:{col_width}} ==> {str(type(i)):{col_width}}')
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Result until list is OK.

```
> Ciao            ==> <class 'str'>  
>               1 ==> <class 'bool'> 
>             2.5 ==> <class 'float'>
>              18 ==> <class 'int'>  
>               1 ==> <class 'int'>  
>         (8+15j) ==> <class 'complex'>
```

What is wrong with the list item of the list?

Thank you!

My code is as follows:

```
my_list = ['Ciao', True, 2.5, 18, 0x001, 8+15j, [5,'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]]]
print(my_list)
col_width=15
for i in my_list:
    print(f'{i:{col_width}} ==> {str(type(i)):{col_width}}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @CoryKramer's answer

Since you're already converting each item of the list with str() then you can use .lstrip() to strip away 'frozenset' whenever it is part of the string.

```
my_list = [
    'Ciao', True, 2.5, 18, 0x001, 8 + 15j, [5, 'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]], frozenset(['one', 'two', 3])
]

col_width = 20

for i in my_list:
    print(f"{str(i).lstrip('frozenset'):{col_width}} ==> {str(type(i)):{col_width}}")
```

Output:

```
Ciao                 ==> <class 'str'>       
True                 ==> <class 'bool'>      
2.5                  ==> <class 'float'>     
18                   ==> <class 'int'>       
1                    ==> <class 'int'>       
(8+15j)              ==> <class 'complex'>   
[5, 'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]] ==> <class 'list'>      
({'one', 3, 'two'})  ==> <class 'frozenset'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert to `str(i)` instead of directly passing `i`

```
for i in my_list:
    print(f'{str(i):{col_width}} ==> {str(type(i)):{col_width}}')
#            ^ here
```

Output

```
Ciao            ==> <class 'str'>  
True            ==> <class 'bool'> 
2.5             ==> <class 'float'>
18              ==> <class 'int'>  
1               ==> <class 'int'>  
(8+15j)         ==> <class 'complex'>
[5, 'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]] ==> <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much!

Comment: but in case of frozenset, for example,  frozenset({'1:5', 'name:"Richard'}), how do i avoid 'frozenset word in output? Because just need to display ==> <class 'frozenset'>, but now it shows frozenset({'1:5', 'name:"Richard'})           ==> <class 'frozenset'>

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr` to coerce your list to a `str`. That makes format available :

```
print(f"{repr(a):40} => {str(type(a)):40}")
```

This prints

```
[5, 'cacao', [2.2, 'Torino', False]]     => <class 'list'>
```

as expected, I guess.